# Daniel 11:30 - Romans?

Tags: prophecy, hebrew-bible, daniel, onomastics, geography

I am reading through [A New English Translation of the Septuagint](http://ccat.sas.upenn.edu/nets/), currently in the Book of Daniel, where two different versions, the Old Greek and Theodotion, are given.

The Old Greek NETS version of Daniel 11:30 reads:

And the Romans will come and will expel him and rebuke him. And he will turn back [and will be angered] against the covenant of the holy one.

The NETS version of Theodotion reads:

And the Kitians who go forth will come against him, and he will be humbled, and he will return and will be enraged against the holy covenant, and he will take action and will return and will gain an understanding with those who forsake the holy covenant.

Other English translations seem to either refer to the ships of Chittim/Kittim, or the ships of Cyprus, or just "western coastlands".

See: https://biblehub.com/daniel/11-30.htm

The Hebrew phrase is צִיִּ֤ים צִיִּ֤ים ([*ṣî·yîm kit·tîm*](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/daniel/11-30.htm)).

As far as the LXX is concerned, all the Greek texts online, that I can find, read Κίτιοι.

My questions are:

1.) Who are these people? Are they indeed Romans, as the NETS version of the Old Greek text reads?

2.) How does the Greek of the Old Greek version of Daniel 11:30 read? Is there a distinct word there that would necessitate a different English translation, such as was done in the NETS Theodotion translation of Daniel 11:30?

3.) If Romans is the correct reading, in what way does that affect the understanding of the passage according to it's fulfillment in historical time?

Answer (score 1):

Let us begin with the Hebrew - in Dan 11:30 the operative word is כִּתִּ֖ים (Kitti or Kittiyyi but always plural) whose meaning is given in the appendix below which occurs just eight times in the OT as listed below.

| Ref | Hebrew (MT) - NASB | LXX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Gen 10:4 | The sons of Javan were Elishah, Tarshish, **Kittim**, and Dodanim. | And the sons of Jovan, Elisa, and Tharseis, **Cetians (Κίτιοι)**, Rhodians |
| Num 24:24 | “But ships shall come from the coast of **Kittim**, And they shall oppress Asshur and oppress Eber; So they also will come to destruction.” | And one shall come forth from the hands of the **Citians (Κιτιαίων)**, and shall afflict Assur, and shall afflict the Hebrews, and they shall perish together. |
| 1 Chron 1:7 | The sons of Javan were Elishah, Tarshish, **Kittim**, and Rodanim. | And the sons of Jovan, Helisa, and Tharsis, the **Citians (Κίτιοι)**, and Rhodians. |
| Isa 23:1 | The pronouncement concerning Tyre: Wail, you ships of Tarshish, For Tyre is destroyed, without house or harbor; It is reported to them from the land of **Cyprus**. | The word concerning Tyre. Howl, ye ships of Carthage; for she has perished, and [men] no longer arrive from the land of the **Citians (Κιτιαίων)**: she is led captive. |
| Isa 23:12 | He has said, “You shall not be jubilant anymore, you crushed virgin daughter of Sidon. Arise, pass over to **Cyprus**; even there you will find no rest.” | And [men] shall say, Ye shall no longer at all continue to insult and injure the daughter of Sidon: and if thou depart to the **Citians (Κιτιεῖς)**, neither there shalt thou have rest. |
| Jer 2:10 | “For cross to the coastlands of **Kittim** and see, And send to Kedar and observe closely, And see if there has been anything like this! | For go to the isles of the **Chettians (Χεττιεὶμ)**, and see; and send to Kedar, and observe accurately, and see if such things have been done; |
| Eze 27:6 | “Of oaks from Bashan they have made your rudders; With ivory they have inlaid your deck of boxwood from the coastlands of **Cyprus**. | They made thine oars [of wood] out of the land of Basan; thy sacred utensils they made of ivory, thy shady houses of wood from the isles of **Chetiim (Χετιείμ)**. |
| Dan 11:30 | For ships of **Kittim** will come against him; therefore he will withdraw in fear and will return and curse the holy covenant and take action; so he will come back and pay attention to those who abandon the holy covenant. | For the **Citians (Κίτιοι)** issuing forth shall come against him, and he shall be brought low, and shall return, and shall be incensed against the holy covenant: and he shall do [thus], and shall return, and have intelligence with them that have forsaken the holy covenant. [Bretton, Swete, Theodoton] // **Ῥωμαῖοι = "Romans"** [Rahlfs] |

Note that many versions of LXX consistently translate כִּתִּ֖ים (Kittim) as Κίτιοι or similar.  However, a few versions of the LXX were biased to translate the word as "Romans".

**APPENDIX - כִּתִּ֖ים (Kitti or Kittiyyi)**

> [כִּתִּי] adjective, of a people always plural כִּתִּים כִּתִּיִּים;
> usually as name, of a people = Cypriotes (compare Phoenician proper
> name, of a location כת כתי, Citium; on a connection with Kheta, –-t¹,
> –attê, חִתִּי, see WMMAsien u. Europa,345; — on Citium see
> CesnolaGyprus 46 ff); — אֶרֶץ כִּתִּים Isaiah 23:1, כִּתִּיי֯ם Isaiah
> 23:12; כִּתִּים (as son of Yawan) Genesis 10:4 = 1 Chronicles 1:7;
> וְצִים ׳מִיַּד כ Numbers 24:24 ships from the side (direction) of
> Kittim; more Generally, of coast-lands of Mediterranean, אִיֵּי
> כִּתִּיִּים Jeremiah 2:10, אִיֵּי כִּתִּיִּם Ezekiel 27:6; even of
> Macedonian Greece, צִיִּים כִּתִּים Daniel 11:30 (only here as
> adjective, compare Bev) i.e. Grecian ships.

Comment: Hi Dottard, and I'm glad to see you are still surprisingly productive in answering many difficult passages. Kudos. So the kittim/kittym were Cyprian, not Roman, but later editors manipulated the text to suggest that it was the "Romans"? IE: This was a case of heavy handed manipulation of holy writ?

Comment: @Ruminator - Many thanks - good to see you again.  The LXX is far from monolithic - several different MSS traditions exist and some show distinct Jewish bias and other infelicities. This is a perfect example. In Dan 11:30 we have two different text types.

Answer (score 1):

Verses 29-30 say that Antiochus’ fourth invasion would not end in his favor. The last invasion “shall not be like the former or the latter.” 29

What prompted this fourth invasion was the unification of his nephews, Ptolemy VI and Physcon (Ptolemy VIII). Both had come to suspect the plans of Antiochus and agreed to join their forces and rule Egypt jointly. This did not set well with Antiochus who wanted the country divided.

> When Antiochus learned of this, he prepared to invade Egypt again in
> 167 BC.  He sent his fleet to Cyprus to secure possession of the
> island and led his army toward Egypt to subdue the two Ptolemies and
> annex the whole country to his dominion. (Barnes Notes)

To prepare for an invasion by Antiochus, the two brothers hired mercenary troops from Greece and requested the support of the Roman navy. In response, the Ships of Kittim arrived from Phoenicia bringing the Roman ambassadors, and their companions to insure the peace. Antiochus had no desire to go to war against Rome so, he abandoned his efforts against Egypt and returned home in anger which he proceeded to measure out on the Jews as the following verses show.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no doubt that The author of TH’s translation of Daniel 11 saw the pericop of Daniel 9-11 as being fulfilled by the Romans.

But TH is a post New Testament Christian Interpolation, so it’s not going to help you understand the original meaning of this passage in the Vorlage of Daniel.

I’d recommend that you try to find the OG version of this section of Daniel, if it exists, and then try to figure out what that text meant. There is no more complicated a hermeneutical puzzle than trying to untangle the LXX version of this section of Daniel. Good luck. But this is why the MT version of Daniel is preferred even though most text critics believe that it is not the earliest text.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/43468)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).